# Resizing absolute positioned div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, css-position

I am working on [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/rLpc90sk/) and am experiencing strange behavior when I want to resize the `.outer` div using jQuery. As you can see on demo and following image the `.outer` div jams once before starting on resizing.

[image]

I have to use absolute positioned div `.inner` inside the `.outer` div as:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner" id="circle"></div>
</div>
<button id="plus" type="button" class="btn">Resize</button>
```

```
$(function () {
    $("#plus").on("click", function () {
        $(".outer").animate({
            width: '+=20px',
            height: '+=20px',
            borderRadius: '+=10px'
        }, {
            duration: 500,
            queue: false
        });
        $(".outer").animate({
            left: '-=1%',
            top: '-=1%'
        }, {
            duration: 500,
            queue: false
        });
    });
});
```

and here is the CSS rules:

```
#circle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fc2e5a;
    -moz-border-radius: 120px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 120px;
    border-radius: 120px;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-100px 0 0 -150px;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
}
.outer {
    position:relative;
    width: 235px;
    height: 220px;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same `height` and `width` for for both `.outer` and `.inner`div.

```
#circle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

So you don't need to use `left`, `top` and `margin` on `#circle` to align that div properly.

Just remove these properties from `#circle` -

```
#circle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fc2e5a;
    -moz-border-radius: 120px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 120px;
    border-radius: 120px;
/*  left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-100px 0 0 -150px; */
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/yc9694vt/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

remove following three lines of css:

```
left:50%;
top:50%;
margin:-100px 0 0 -150px;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rLpc90sk/2/

Answer (score 0):

There is one more thing that needs to be removed from the function in order to fix the behavior were the circle is compressed or shrinks before it increases in size after the click. Remove the  left: '-=1%' and top: '-=1%', properties from the second animate entry in the function.  Along with the first suggestions above and voila, the circle expands without the shrinking left and bottom animation.

```
$(".outer").animate({      

        }, {
```